# How to use 'tap' in bokeh to effect changes in a different plot (or table)?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to create a bokeh dashboard (using only `python`, not `JS`!) in which by clicking on a glyph in one plot it affects the output of a table in the same dashboard. For some reason I am able to click and select the point but I see no change in the table. (Also for some reason it does not print to console so I find it hard to debug (?)) I have tried many different things with no luck. If anybody could provide any input I would really appreciate it. The Code follows. The code below existed under the name `"main.py"` and was in a folder called `"select_exp"`. The bokeh server was launched with:
bokeh serve select_exp.
Again thanks in advance for any help!
Gino

`

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn

# Create data for plot
x = [0, 1]
y = [0, 1]
table_index = [0, 1]

# Create the plot (this will be clicked on)
plot = figure(height = 400, width = 600,
              title='Select a point', tools='tap')
plot_source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x=x, y=y))
renderer = plot.circle('x',  'y', source=plot_source, size=30)


# Create two sets of data for the tablet
master_data = {}
master_data[0] = {'animals': ['dog', 'cat', 'cow', 'mouse'],
                   'plants': ['carrot', 'catnip', 'grass', 'cheese']}
master_data[1] = {'animals': ['elephant', 'lion', 'monkey', 'emu'],
                  'plants': ['grass', 'turnips', 'banana', 'petunias']}

# Create a table
data = master_data[0]
table_source = ColumnDataSource(data)
columns = [  TableColumn(field='animals', title = 'Animal'),
             TableColumn(field='plants',  title = 'Plant')   ]
data_table = DataTable(source=table_source, columns=columns,
                       width=400, height=600)

# Here the reactions of the server are defined
def my_tap_handler(attr, old, new):
    index = source.selected.indices
    print(index)
    data_table.source = ColumnDataSource(master_data[index])

renderer.data_source.on_change("selected", my_tap_handler)

# Collect it all together iin the current doc
curdoc().add_root(column(plot, data_table))
curdoc().title = 'Select experiment'
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bokeh v1.0.4 you need to apply the callback to the `selected` property of the `data_source` and on the `indices` attribute. Run the code with `bokeh serve --show app.py`

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn

# Create data for plot
x = [0, 1]
y = [0, 1]
table_index = [0, 1]

# Create the plot (this will be clicked on)
plot = figure(height = 400, width = 600,
              title = 'Select a point', tools = 'tap')
plot_source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x = x, y = y))
renderer = plot.circle('x', 'y', source = plot_source, size = 30)

# Create two sets of data for the tablet
master_data = {}
master_data[0] = {'animals': ['dog', 'cat', 'cow', 'mouse'],
                   'plants': ['carrot', 'catnip', 'grass', 'cheese']}
master_data[1] = {'animals': ['elephant', 'lion', 'monkey', 'emu'],
                  'plants': ['grass', 'turnips', 'banana', 'petunias']}

# Create a table
data = master_data[0]
table_source = ColumnDataSource(data)
columns = [  TableColumn(field = 'animals', title = 'Animal'),
             TableColumn(field = 'plants', title = 'Plant')   ]
data_table = DataTable(source = table_source, columns = columns,
                       width = 400, height = 600)

# Here the reactions of the server are defined
def my_tap_handler(attr, old, new):
    index = new[0]
    data_table.source = ColumnDataSource(master_data[index])

plot_source.selected.on_change("indices", my_tap_handler)

# Collect it all together in the current doc
curdoc().add_root(column(plot, data_table))
curdoc().title = 'Select experiment'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you very much Tony. Just wondering in what document would I have found this information so next time I don't have to ask questions but figure it out myself. Thanks again

Comment: Please have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403853/how-to-get-a-list-of-bokeh-widget-events-and-attributes-which-can-be-used-to-tr/55406351#55406351) It should help you a little bit. In general it is not so well documented so you need to analyse several examples to learn these things. In this particular example `selected` is a property of [ColumnDataSource](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html) that holds information about selected indices.