# Trigger a JavaScript callback upon ColumnDataSource change in a plot

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

Is there a way in Bokeh to trigger a JavaScript callback when a ColumnDataSource is updated with new data?

I'm looking for something similar to this...

```py
cds1 = ColumnDataSource(some_pandas_dataframe)
cds1.js_onchange('', callback) # attach some kind of callback here to do something when cds1.data changes.
cds2 = ColumnDataSource(some_pandas_dataframe)

cds1.data.update(cds2.data)
```

Comment: Don't you running a Bokeh server app and shouldn't be using rather a Python callback for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it in Bokeh v1.1.0 is to attach a callback to the `data` attribute of `ColumnDataSource`:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, show, curdoc
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Button, Column
from bokeh.events import Tap

cds = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x = [0.1, 0.9], y = [0.1, 0.9]))
p = Figure(x_range = (0, 1), y_range = (0, 1), tools = "")
p.scatter(x = 'x', y = 'y', source = cds)

data = dict(x = [0.5], y = [0.5])
callback = CustomJS(args = {'cds': cds, 'data': data}, code = "cds.data = data")

button = Button(label = 'click me')
button.js_on_event('button_click', callback)

cds.js_on_change('data', CustomJS(code = "alert('data_change_detected');"))

show(Column(p, button))
```

Comment: Thank You! js_on_change('data' is what I was looking for. How do you find all of the different events to listen to?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403853/how-to-get-a-list-of-bokeh-widget-events-and-attributes-which-can-be-used-to-tr/55406351#55406351) contains some relevant links to Bokeh documentation as well as my attempt to provide an overview on this subject.